# ERROR CANNOT ASSIGN TO A NAMED CONSTANT

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran

I have written a very simple program in Fortran:

```
      parameter(m_box=7)      ! Number of urns (not a real parameter)
      parameter(max_dens=4) ! Maximum density computed
      parameter(beta=4.5)  

      real*8 p(0:m_box*max_dens),mbeta,xnorm
      real*8 hist(0:m_box*(max_dens**2),0:(max_dens*m_box)**2)
      real*8 Pi(0:(max_dens*m_box)**2)
      integer sum2,sumq
      n_balls=m_box*max_dens
      n2_balls=m_box*(max_dens**2)
      nq_balls=(m_box*max_dens)**2 
      n2half=(int(sqrt(n2_balls/2.))+1)**2       ! Valore massimo per il quale ho tutta la statistica
      mbeta=-beta
      freq=log(20.)

      xnorm=0.
      do n=0,n_balls
         p(n)=(n+1.)**mbeta    ! Urns
         xnorm=xnorm+p(n)
      enddo
      do n=0,n_balls
         p(n)=p(n)/xnorm
      enddo
      do i=0,n2_balls
      do j=0,nq_balls
         pi(i)=0
         hist(i,j)=0
      enddo
      enddo

      do n1=0,n_balls
      do n2=0,n_balls
      do n3=0,n_balls
      do n4=0,n_balls
      do n5=0,n_balls
      do n6=0,n_balls
      do n7=0,n_balls
      sum2=n1**2+n2**2+n3**2+n4**2+n5**2+n6**2+n7**2
      sumq=(n1+n2+n3+n4+n5+n6+n7)**2
      if(sum2 .le. n2_balls .and. sumq .le. nq_balls)hist(sum2,sumq)=
     &   hist(sum2,sumq)+p(n1)*p(n2)*p(n3)*p(n4)*p(n5)*                 
     &    p(n6)*p(n7)
      if((sum2 .eq. n2half) .and. (sumq .eq. nq_balls))Pi(n1)=
     &    Pi(n1)+p(n1)*p(n2)*p(n3)*p(n4)*p(n5)*
     &    p(n6)*p(n7)!*p(n8)*p(n9)*p(n10)

      enddo
      enddo 
      enddo
      enddo
      enddo
      enddo
            write(102,*)n1,Pi(n1)   
      enddo
      sumhist=0
      do i=0,n2_balls
      do j=0,nq_nqballs
        sumhist=sumhist+hist(i,j)
      if(hist(i,j).ne.0)write(100,*)i,hist(i,j)
      if(hist(i,j).ne.0)write(101,*)1.*i/m_box,-log(1d0*hist(i,j))/m_box
      enddo
      enddo
      print*,'Normalizzazione della P = ',sumhist
      end
```

When I compile I get the error:

```
ERROR CANNOT ASSIGN TO A NAMED CONSTANT f:45:55.
```

I surely made a stupid error but I can't see where. I'm pretty sure that the if statement is right because I used it in a another program and it worked.

Comment: Which is the referenced line?  And this should be fixed-form source, I guess, so please pay careful attention to the formatting of the code you present: you may need to indent further, but as it is that isn't valid code.

Comment: Please, use some spacing. The code is horrible, almost unreadable. Very difficult to check for errors. For example `if(hist(i,j).ne.0)write(100,*)i,hist(i,j)` should be at least `if (hist(i,j).ne.0) write(100,*) i, hist(i,j)`. I would put there even more spaces. Also use spaces for indenting the nested do loops.

Comment: @francescalus I think Stackoverflow eats several spaces when copy pasting and treats them as indentation of a code block and not indentation inside the code block itself.

Comment: @VladimirF Yes, it's likely this code block just needs the four spaces on each line put back in.  I'm just reluctant to do that without confirmation that the post owner is intending it be fixed-form source (the broken continuation with free-form may actually be the problem).

Comment: I rolled your edit back. It didn't make anything useful, but made the code even worse indented. Your ampersands ended up in completely wrong positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing tabs and spaces. You can't do that in Fortran and definitely not in fixed form Fortran. This is how the code looks like in my editor after converting the tabs to spaces:

```
              do n1=0,n_balls
              do n2=0,n_balls
              do n3=0,n_balls
              do n4=0,n_balls
              do n5=0,n_balls
              do n6=0,n_balls
              do n7=0,n_balls
              sum2=n1**2+n2**2+n3**2+n4**2+n5**2+n6**2+n7**2
              sumq=(n1+n2+n3+n4+n5+n6+n7)**2
              if(sum2 .le. n2_balls .and. sumq .le. nq_balls)hist(sum2,sumq)=
            &   hist(sum2,sumq)+p(n1)*p(n2)*p(n3)*p(n4)*p(n5)*                 
        &    p(n6)*p(n7)
              if((sum2 .eq. n2half) .and. (sumq .eq. nq_balls))Pi(n1)=
        &    Pi(n1)+p(n1)*p(n2)*p(n3)*p(n4)*p(n5)*
        &    p(n6)*p(n7)!*p(n8)*p(n9)*p(n10)

              enddo
          enddo
```

You can see that the first ampersand `&` is indented wrong!

You must convert all tabs to spaces and never use tabs again. Also you must fix the indentation. Several lines may become too long too and you will have to break them.

Set up your editor to use spaces, when you press the TAB key.